# What is the fundamental matrix solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a 3 by 3 matrix, such that $\dot{x}=Ax$. I am trying to find the fundamental matrix solution. I know that I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ which I did but I am not sure what to do next. Does anyone know what to once you find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the fundamental matrix of a system of differential equations?

Comment: @cheesyfluff, yes.

Comment: Do you know about matrix exponentials?

Comment: @JackM, Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have three unique eigenvalues $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ and eigenvectors $(\pmb{\xi}^{(1)},\pmb{\xi}^{(2)},\pmb{\xi}^{(3)})$ you should have three linearly independent solutions in the form
$$\mathbf{x}_1(t)=\pmb{\xi}^{(1)} e^{\lambda_1t}\qquad
\mathbf{x}_2(t)=\pmb{\xi}^{(2)} e^{\lambda_2t}\qquad
\mathbf{x}_3(t)=\pmb{\xi}^{(3)} e^{\lambda_3t}$$
Then your fundamental matrix should be
$$\pmb{\psi}(t)=\left(
\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
\mathbf{x}_1(t)&
\mathbf{x}_2(t)&
\mathbf{x}_3(t)
\end{array}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
\xi_1^{(1)e^{\lambda_1t}}&\xi_1^{(2)e^{\lambda_2t}}&\xi_1^{(3)e^{\lambda_3t}}\\
\xi_2^{(1)e^{\lambda_1t}}&\xi_2^{(2)e^{\lambda_2t}}&\xi_2^{(3)e^{\lambda_3t}}\\
\xi_3^{(1)e^{\lambda_1t}}&\xi_3^{(2)e^{\lambda_2t}}&\xi_3^{(3)e^{\lambda_3t}}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $\xi_n^{(m)}$ denotes the $n$th element of $\pmb{\xi}^{(m)}$. Note that the general solution of the differential equation is
$$\mathbf{x}=\pmb{\psi}(t)\mathbf{c}$$
where $\mathbf{c}=(c_1,c_2,c_3)^\intercal$ is a constant matrix.